# Filter the content of array using another string array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have written this simple search Pipe and it is working fine.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'search'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(userItems: UserItemModel[], searchTerm: string): UserItemModel[] {

    if (!userItems) { return []; }

    if (!searchTerm) { return userItems; }

    searchTerm = searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase();

    return userItems.filter(ui => {
      return ui.item?.name?.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(searchTerm);
    });
  }

}
```

Here I can use only a simple string as `searchTerm`. How can I write a new pipe to support an array of strings as a `searchTerms`?

**e.g.** `searchTerms: string[]`

`transform(userItems: UserItemModel[], searchTerms: string[]): UserItemModel[] {`

The use case here is I need to filter the content of an array using a Category filter (i.e. multiple categories).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for the checking. (or [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) depending on your requirement - if wish to filter these which include all the search terms only)

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'search'
  })
  export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  
    transform(userItems: UserItemModel[], searchTerms: string[]): UserItemModel[] {
  
      if (!userItems) { return []; }
  
      if (!searchTerms) { return userItems; }
    
      return userItems.filter(ui => {
        return searchTerms.some(term => ui.item?.name?.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(term.toLocaleLowerCase()));
      });
    }
  
  }
```